# rails seems to delete query params in URL with 'button_to' helper and 'get' method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a list of items displayed in a view, with a "delete" button for each item. When the button is pressed, I want to recall this same page with a `delete_id` param in the url query. My button looks like this :

```
 =button_to t("settings.saved_searches.delete_button"), saved_searches_person_settings_path(:delete_id => saved_search.id), {method: :get ,class:"button delete_search_button", confirm: t("settings.saved_searches.confirm_delete",search_name:saved_search.name)}
```

And it seems it generates want I want :

```
<form class="button_to" method="get" action="/fr/liteultom/settings/saved_searches?delete_id=5">
  <input class="button delete_search_button" confirm="Êtes-vous certain de vouloir supprimer la recherche &quot;test jamais&quot;" type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

But when I press it, It send me back to the path `/fr/liteultom/settings/saved_searches?` , without the `delete_id` param.

Edit : I have the same behavior when calling my home page with some parameters from a "button_to" helper.

What am I missing ?

Edit 2 :
Here is an example of server log when I click this button :

```
<form class="button_to" method="get" action="/fr/homepage?price_max=9271&amp;price_min=0&amp;update_frequency=weekly">
  <input class="button run_search_button" type="submit" value="Lancer">
</form>
```

and instead of landing on :

```
/fr/homepage?price_max=9271&amp;price_min=0&amp;update_frequency=weekly
```

I land on: `/fr/homepage?`

Logs :

```
16:08:03 rails.1               | 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Jul/2018:16:07:54 CEST] "GET /fr/homepage? HTTP/1.1" 200 15015
16:08:03 rails.1               | http://my.server.me:5000/fr/liteultom/settings/saved_searches -> /fr/homepage?
```

Comment: Can you add the server logs?

Comment: updated with the two lines of server logs I get. Since this is in sharetribe , "DEBUG" log level i very very verbose so I kept it to INFO. But DEBUG level does not seem to provide any more insight, only DB calls are logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you add `params: { }` at the end of `button_to` inside the braces that hold http_options, it will generate `hidden_field` which contains the value.

```
 params: { :delete_id => saved_search.id }
```

Comment: Well, this works, thank you ! But damn if I can have an explanation of why the path is modified, i'd love that too. Any way, thank you.

Comment: @Tom it may not be a Rails thing but an browser/HTML/HTTP thing.  Browsers respond to a form element's "submit" event by generating an HTTP POST request.  Forms can be configured with `method="get"` to instead send HTTP GET.  An HTTP GET request has no body, so its only place to store params is the URL's query string.  But a browser is used to using inputs inside a form to develop a list of parameters for a request.  Having both inputs and a query string defined on a form would mean two (potentially conflicting) sources of information.  The browser discards the query string and uses the inputs

Comment: oh. This seems to make sense. Thank you for the explanation !

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add a suggestion incase this may help others, the above answer did help me get closer to solving my problem but not quite.

I needed to send an id as params through a submit button so I added the params to my controller then added a hidden field right above.

Add this inside your form and above your button.

```
= f.hidden_field :params, value: params.id
```